# Terminal suddenly disappeared from my MacOS Yosemite

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

I just had to reboot for the first time in weeks... after the reboot, I noticed that two elements were missing from my dock: Unity3D and my Terminal (more precisely, they had been replaced with interrogation marks).

I went to look for those apps in my filesystem, and there's no trace of them anywhere. I have *no* idea how, when and why they have been removed.

But I need my Terminal for my work.

I've already tried alternatives for OSX's terminal, and none of them are really what I'm looking for... but the original one is by far the closest to what I want. How do I get it back ?

Thanks.

EDIT: Interesting point: I tried installing alternatives for the terminal... unfortunately none of them launched. I'm thinking there's a component needed by terminals that has gone missing as well.
I also noticed the System Monitor is missing as well.

Comment: Restore from Time Machine ?

Comment: Or reinstall the OS over top of the existing installation. I have no idea what might've caused this, so I'd be worried those might not be the only things missing, and a reinstall should take care of whatever's missing.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I'm not sure how Time Machine works. But supposing what you were suggesting was to launch Time Machine, go to the `/Application` folder, and look for the applications at a time when they were there... well I went over all the backups that I could: the applications are still missing, even a week back, despite the fact that I've been using them daily for months.

Comment: Gordon's might be a better idea, but Terminal should be in Apps/Utils by default, idk where Unity might live

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Don't I need a DVD of Yosemite to do that ? Because I'm pretty sure I didn't update to Yosemite using a DVD. Is there a way to re-install without the DVD ?

Comment: you do it from the Recovery Partition, or at worst over the Internet -  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Answer (score 0):

I had a sightly different problem, where my terminal randomly disappeared off screen, and I couldn't get it back. I knew it was still working because some local hosts it was running were still perfectly operable.

To get it back, look for it in the dock (the black square icon), simply clicking on it and selecting one (any) of the processes it was running brought it back on to the screen.